# js typing text to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i have a problem with a function which runs just fine on my localhost by when i upload it to the server it doesn't work, could some one please point me to the solution:

```
var text = "some text";
var textArray = text.split("");
var looptimer;
function letterloop(){
    if (textArray.length > 0){
        $("#divx").append(textArray.shift());
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(looptimer);
        var div = $("<a href=\"#\" onmousedown=\"javascript:continueOne();\" style=\"margin-top:70px; display:block; text-align:center;\" id=\"continue\" class=\"send_msg_blue\">continue</a>").hide().fadeIn(4000);
        $("#div").append(div);
        return false;
    }
    looptimer = setTimeout("letterloop()",60);
}
letterloop();
```

Comment: Note: don't use `setTimeout()` with the string parameter. Use `setTimeout(letterloop, 60)`.

Comment: that simply caused my function to stop working on localhost as well

Comment: No, it was not this change. [It works and I can prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/VTaqy/).

Comment: sorry, my bad it still works but still only on localhost

Comment: Please don't post things like "it doesn't work". This is absolutely useless to us. Tell us what it's supposed to do and what it actually does and how this differs from your expectations.

Comment: it is supposed to type the text to the screen letter by letter and it also does it when on my localhost as soon as i upload it to my server online the text doesn't show at all

Comment: Works fine for me, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/JgWcM/). Is the code inside the jQuery.ready() handler?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `javascript:` in `onmousedown` attribute. That's only needed in places that can contain a URL (e.g. `href` attributes, bookmarklets).

Comment: thanks for the advises still cant figure out why doesn't it work..ill check my whole code again..

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't upload the `jquery.js` file to your server or include it in the HTML `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the js files like jquery you quoted are on the server